# Push Notification in .Net core 2.1 MVC hosted in WebApp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I am creating my website application in .net core 2.1. I have to deploy it in WebApp of Azure. 
I am bit new to WebApp so not sure if I need to enable **any service or any port** on WebApp so Notfication works. 
Otherwise normal way to show Notification is SignalR implemented. 
1) Will SignalR will work for website hosted in WebApp?

If any Azure service that will do same please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR uses web sockets to connect with clients, so you will need to go into app settings and enable them for SignalR to work.

Here is a tutorial to help you set up your WebApp with SignalR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Based on your scenario, [Azure SignalR Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) or [Azure Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) may be an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is notification service in Azure Web Apps around sending push notification to Mobile Devices that are integrated with Azure.

In your case i assume you are talking about sending real time notifications within the web app ? Yes SignalR works great for that scenario , and you can look into dedicated SignalR service from Azure for this.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/signalr-service/